# Extract large data from iterator into DataFrame

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, iterator

I'm extracting a large dataset (38M records) from Teradata into Python DataFrame.  Here's my query:

```
sql = 'SELECT *
from retail.consumer
where unit = Texas'

df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, chunksize = 100000)

ef = []
while True:
    try:
        a = next(df)
        ef.append(a)
        data = pd.DataFrame(ef)

    except StopIteration:
        break:
data
```

After about 10minutes my kernel will stop, which kills the processing.  Is there a faster way to extract the data from the iterator and export it to the DataFrame?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should use `Dask` instead of `Pandas`.

Comment: your loop does not make sense, why do you convert to a DataFrame on every iteration? it should wait until the end

Comment: @gold_cy thanks!  I definitely misplaced the DataFrame in this loop.  I will remove this line and place it at the end of the code.

Comment: @gold_cy unfortunately this did not resolve the error.  Is there a way to get this data from the iterator into the DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Since `chunksize` returns an iterator, simply iterate directly on that object, build your list of data frame chunks then concatenate outside the loop. Right now in each loop you are calling `DataFrame` on a `list` object that grows in the loop!

```py
df_iter = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, chunksize = 100000)

df_chunk_list = []
for df in df_iter:
    df_chunk_list.append(df)
    
data = pd.concat(df_chunk_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: unfortunately this suggestion produced the following error: 
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'generator'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: Actually, I do not get such an error in testing this code. Only `df_iter` comes in as a generator object but that is not being concatenated in `pandas.concat`. Other objects return as they should be: `df` as data frame, `df_chunk_list` as list of data frames, and `data` as data frame.